# MOSS 2007 Search not working in Custom List

Tags: 2007, search, custom-list

We have a custom list with a field that is single line of text, 10 characters.  When the user uses the default ShaerPoint search box at the top right of the page to search for a value in the list, they fail if the value is more than 8 characters long.  It will find list items where this field is 8 character long.  I have found that the list contains ~4400 items.

The user can filter the list by clicking on the column and choosing "Show Filter Choices" but this adds steps to get what they are looking for.

Any ideas of why this search is failing, other than perhaps the number of items?

Comment: is it new list? did you perform the full crawl?

Comment: No, this list has been around for some time.  I hear the search used to work.  Not sure about the "full crawl", this is MOSS 2007 not 2013.

Comment: full crawl exist in 2007, try to run the full crawl from central admin then try it.